# How does Powershell create fake drive labels in Windows?

Tags: windows, powershell, filesystems

In Powershell (at least in Windows 10EE), certain parts of the system are exposed under a custom drive label. The two main examples I know are:

1. `HKLM:` exposes the local machine's registry as a drive.
2. `$Env:` exposes the environment variables like their own filesystem.

However, cmd and batch scripts are not able to see these drives.

So my questions are:

- How does Powershell implement these fake drive labels?
- Are they similar to mountpoints in Linux?
- Are they using some kind of pseudo-filesystem under the hood?

Comment: Read `Get-Help New-PsDrive`,`Get-Help about_Providers` or view [online](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-psdrive?view=powershell-5.1), [about_Providers](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_providers?view=powershell-5.1)

Comment: It has nothing to do with Drive Letter (it is obviously more than a single letter, ain't it?). It is more like internet protocols. http://, ftp:// and remember Windows Help in CHM (compiled HTML) format? There is a special protocol too, mk-itsf:// or something like that. Some programs in Linux utilize the same concept too, example Gnome VFS. On the filesystem level, there are no any "drive labels" in UNIX, at all. But exposing non-files in files tree is the basic idea of UNIX from 1970-s. In Linux too. DevFS, ProcFS, SysFS, FUSE. Also google about Plan9 OS that thinks UNIX does not do enough

Comment: What exactly is "*Windows 10EE*"?

Comment: @Ramhound Windows 10, Enterprise Edition

Comment: @EdwardMinnix - That is simply `Windows 10 Enterprise`.  Referring to it as `Windows 10 EE` will confuse people.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In PowerShell, those are called [PSProviders](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_providers?view=powershell-6)

> PowerShell providers are Microsoft .NET Framework-based programs that
>   make the data in a specialized data store available in PowerShell so
>   that you can view and manage it.

cmd / batch is not .NET Framework based, that's why they can't use them.

Comment: It has less to do with .net framework and more with Powershell itself. This is purely Powershell concept, so they are not available outside of Powersell at all.